# Cannot fix broken WSL Distribution

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL on Windows 10 v1909.  The distribution is Pengwin and everything was fine until today.  Now I cannot install anything nor fix the broken distribution due to being unable to delete `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0` as I always get a permission denied.  I've tried every trick in the book to delete the file in both Linux and Windows with no luck.  Here's is what happens when I try to fix the install:

```bsh
 sudo apt --fix-broken install
[sudo] password for [redacted]:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aglfn aspell aspell-en asymptote-doc biber bubblewrap chktex cm-super cm-super-minimal context context-modules dictionaries-common dvidvi dvipng
  emacsen-common enchant fcitx-frontend-qt4 feynmf fonts-adf-accanthis fonts-adf-berenis fonts-adf-gillius fonts-adf-universalis
  fonts-arphic-bkai00mp fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp fonts-arphic-gkai00mp fonts-baekmuk fonts-cabin fonts-cantarell fonts-comfortaa
  fonts-croscore fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ebgaramond fonts-ebgaramond-extra fonts-font-awesome
  fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-baskerville fonts-gfs-bodoni-classic fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-didot-classic fonts-gfs-gazis
  fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-porson fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-gfs-theokritos fonts-go fonts-hosny-amiri fonts-junicode fonts-lato
  fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-lobster fonts-lobstertwo fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-hinted fonts-noto-ui-core fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-open-sans
  fonts-roboto-unhinted fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic fonts-sil-gentiumplus fonts-sil-gentiumplus-compact fonts-sil-padauk fonts-stix
  fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-garuda-otf fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-kinnari-otf fonts-tlwg-laksaman fonts-tlwg-laksaman-otf fonts-tlwg-loma
  fonts-tlwg-loma-otf fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-mono-otf fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-norasi-otf fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-purisa-otf
  fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-otf fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typewriter-otf fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typist-otf
  fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-typo-otf fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-umpush-otf fonts-tlwg-waree fonts-tlwg-waree-otf fonts-unfonts-core
  fonts-unfonts-extra fragmaster gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x
  hunspell-en-us info intel-media-va-driver ipython iso-codes javascript-common lacheck latex-cjk-all latex-cjk-chinese
  latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp
  latex-cjk-common latex-cjk-japanese latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab latex-cjk-korean latex-cjk-thai latexdiff latexmk lcdf-typetools libaa1 libaacs0
  libalgorithm-c3-perl libaom0 libaspell15 libass9 libasyncns0 libaudio2 libautovivification-perl libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavfilter7
  libavformat58 libavutil56 libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libbtparse2
  libbusiness-isbn-data-perl libbusiness-isbn-perl libbusiness-ismn-perl libbusiness-issn-perl libcaca0 libcdparanoia0 libchromaprint1
  libclass-accessor-perl libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-inspector-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl
  libclass-singleton-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl libcodec2-0.8.1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdata-compare-perl
  libdata-optlist-perl libdata-uniqid-perl libdate-simple-perl libdatetime-calendar-julian-perl libdatetime-format-builder-perl
  libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl libdatetime-timezone-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-caller-perl                                                                                                            libdevel-globaldestruction-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdist-checkconflicts-perl libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-radeon1 libdv4 libdynaloader-functions-perl libemail-date-format-perl libemf1 libenchant1c2a libencode-eucjpms-perl libencode-hanextra-perl                                                                                                            libencode-jis2k-perl libencode-perl libeval-closure-perl libexception-class-perl libexporter-tiny-perl libfile-find-rule-perl libfile-homedir-perl                                                                                                            libfile-sharedir-perl libfile-slurper-perl libfile-which-perl libflac8 libflite1 libgd3 libgfortran5 libgme0 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgsl23
  libgslcblas0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libhunspell-1.7-0 libhyphen0 libiec61883-0 libigdgmm11 libigdgmm9
  libilmbase23 libimagequant0 libipc-run3-perl libipc-shareable-perl libisl19 libjack-jackd2-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjs-jquery
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore liblapack3 liblilv-0-0 liblingua-translit-perl liblist-allutils-perl liblist-moreutils-perl
  liblist-someutils-perl liblist-someutils-xs-perl liblist-utilsby-perl libllvm9 liblog-dispatch-perl liblog-log4perl-perl libmagick++-6.q16-8                                                                                                                  libmail-sendmail-perl libmime-charset-perl libmime-lite-perl libmime-types-perl libmng1 libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl                                                                                                                  libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libmro-compat-perl libmysofa0 libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl libnorm1 libnumber-compare-perl
  libopenexr23 libopenmpt0 libopus0 liborc-0.4-0 libosp5 libostyle1c2 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpadwalker-perl libpango-perl                                                                                                            libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparams-validate-perl libparams-validationcompiler-perl libpciaccess0 libperl5.28
  libperlio-utf8-strict-perl libpgm-5.2-0 libplot2c2 libpostproc55 libpotrace0 libpstoedit0c2a libpulse0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-xml libqt5xml5
  libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libraw1394-11 libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl libregexp-common-perl librole-tiny-perl
  librubberband2 libruby2.5 libsamplerate0 libsensors-config libsensors5 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libshout3 libsigsegv2 libsnappy1v5 libsndfile1
  libsodium23 libsombok3 libsord-0-0 libsort-key-perl libsoxr0 libspecio-perl libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libsub-exporter-perl
  libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-quote-perl libswresample3 libswscale5 libsys-hostname-long-perl                                                                                                              libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla libtcl8.6 libtext-bibtex-perl libtext-csv-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl libtext-glob-perl libtext-roman-perl
  libtext-unidecode-perl libtheora0 libtie-cycle-perl libtk8.6 libtwolame0 libunicode-collate-perl libunicode-linebreak-perl libutempter0 libv4l-0                                                                                                              libv4lconvert0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvariable-magic-perl libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvisual-0.4-0 libvorbisenc2 libvpx5 libvpx6
  libwavpack1 libwebpdemux2 libx264-155 libx265-165 libx265-176 libxcb-glx0 libxml-libxml-simple-perl libxml-libxslt-perl libxml-writer-perl
  libxslt1.1 libxstring-perl libxv1 libxvidcore4 libxxf86dga1 libxxhash0 libyaml-0-2 libyaml-tiny-perl libz3-4 libzip4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common
  libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers openjade perl-modules-5.28 pfb2t1c2pfb prerex preview-latex-style ps2eps pstoedit psutils purifyeps                                                                                                               texlive-lang-other texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese texlive-lang-spanish texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-extra
  texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-metapost texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music
  texlive-pictures texlive-pictures-doc texlive-plain-generic texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc texlive-publishers texlive-publishers-doc
  texlive-science texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex tipa tk tk8.6 tkinfo xbitmaps xdg-dbus-proxy xterm zenity-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgles2
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdrm-intel1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgles2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
369 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 72.7 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 281756 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.99-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libdrm-intel1:amd64 (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0': Permission denied
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdrm-intel1:amd64
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is the permission of that file till now? Did you try to delete it manually from both WSL and Windows side? Could you provide some background about how it reached this state?

Comment: ```bash
ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0

-rwxrwxrwx 0 root root 147248 Aug 12 04:01 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: I was simply try to do a `sudo apt upgrade` after doing a `sudo apt update`.  Since I started getting the error I've tried clearing the immutable flag which didn't work.  I've tried all manner of trying to delete with powershell which hasn't worked (both in Linux and Windows).

Comment: The simplest solution might be to uninstall and reinstall Pengwin, saving your home folder and any other modified files.